# variable range to array in public function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Below is the code im working on.  I have a 30x29 array that i need to subtract from a 1x30 array and then create a new array from a specified column (Mnth) in the newly created array and finally determine the min value in that array.  I am trying to do this via a public function where i select the ranges and then input the desired column.  Any help would be appreciated

```
Public Function Implied_Ask(Spreads As Range, Bullets As Range, Mnth As Integer)

Dim arr(1 To 30, 1 To 29) As Variant
Dim arr2(1 To 30) As Variant
Dim arr3(1 To 30, 1 To 29) As Variant
Dim arr4(1 To 30) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

arr = Spreads
arr2 = Bullets

For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 To 29
        arr3(i, j) = arr2(i) - arr(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

For k = 1 To 30
    arr4(k) = arr3(k, Mnth)
Next k

Implied_Ask = Application.Min(arr4)

End Function
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code, on which line does it error?

Comment: i am not great in vba by any means but since it is a function i cant step into the code (idk how at least)

Comment: If you can't run the function then how do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes just put a break point at `arr = Spreads` then use F8 to step through till it kicks you out.  The last highlighted line is the error.  Or call the function through a Sub and Excel will show you the offending line.

Comment: all i get is #values in Excel when i attempt to use the function

Comment: Paste this under the **Public Function...** line: `Debug.Print Spreads.Address & "_" & Bullets.Address & "_" & Mnth`.... Press **Ctrl + G** in VBA, and paste the result from the immediate window

Comment: looks to break at
    arr = spreads

Cant assign to array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.Value` to your ranges to assign them to an array. Also, let the range itself determine the size of the array.

Try this:

```
Public Function Implied_Ask(Spreads As Range, Bullets As Range, Mnth As Integer)

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim arr3(1 To 30, 1 To 29) As Variant
Dim arr4(1 To 30) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

arr = Spreads.Value
arr2 = Bullets.Value

For i = 1 To 30
    For j = 1 To 29
        arr3(i, j) = arr2(i, j) - arr(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

For k = 1 To 30
    arr4(k) = arr3(k, Mnth)
Next k

Implied_Ask = Application.Min(arr4)

End Function
```

Comment: this ends with the same problem.  cant assign to array

Comment: You also need to remove the size when declaring an array directly from a range.

Comment: Can you remove the explicit dimension declarations? `Dim arr() As Variant`

Comment: okay, breaking on    arr3(i, j) = arr2(i) - arr(i, j)  now. "subscript out of range"

Comment: `arr2(i)` Needs to be  `arr2(i,1)`

Comment: ty, that did it.  Much appreciated

Comment: here is a follow up to that... any thoughts on how to determine which array values created the min?